# How to Change the Loglevel or Silence All Logs for a Third Party Library in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Here is how my code looks like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding:utf-8
import logging, asyncua 
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

...# Other stuffs
logging.info(msg='My message')
```

But seems like the `asyncua` library has an extremely verbose log setting inside, even at info level. So as I set my loglevel to info or debug, the library itself fills my console with unnecessary (at least to me) messages where my own log messages get lost. The workaround I am using is setting my own loglevel as ERROR to suppress their info/debug log and logging all my messages as error, which seem like a terrible hack to avoid.

So how do I totally silence any log from my imports, or set them all at error/warning level, to make sure my own logs do not get lost in the console? Is there a method that covers all relevant libraries, not just `asyncua`, but also, for example, `tensorflow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out the names of the top-level loggers for your third-party libraries from their documentation or source code (e.g. might be `asyncua`, `tensorflow`) and then set the level of those loggers to suit your need, e.g.

```
logging.getLogger('asyncua').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

and use level `logging.CRITICAL + 1` to completely silence them (assuming they just use the standard logging levels).

Comment: Your sample code works, for ```asyncua``` at least. Is ```'asyncua'``` itself the _name of the top-level logger_ (a string) then?

Comment: @Della I don't use it, you'd have to check the documentation or the source to ascertain the name of the top-level logger. If a library is well-behaved (follows `logging` recommendations) then I would expect the top-level logger name to be the same as the top-level module name.